# Is there a way to add a retry to all methods of a class without manually adding code for each method?

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for something like a decorator I can add on a class which will add a retry mechanism for each method so if new methods are added, the developer won't have to add a retry mechanism or remember to annotate the method.

Is something like this possible in TypeScript?

Comment: Not exactly; that's runtime behaviour, you'd have to implement it in *JavaScript*.

Comment: Can you give an example of what I described in JavaScript?

Answer (score -1):

I guess, [Class Decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators) helps you